# Cmake - Exporting and importing libraries

Tags: cmake

CMake export/import libraries

I want to export and import libraries in cmake in a portable way (windows AND linux).
I want to do it right, clean, with the install target and export commands, however they are quite cryptic and documentation - though complete - gives absolutely no context nor easy example to learn from.
Currently, I have libA's cmakelists :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(libA VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)
# Files
set(PUBLIC_HEADERS
    includes/libA.h
)
set(SOURCE_FILES
    sources/libA.c
)
# Shared library
add_library(libA SHARED 
  ${SOURCE_FILES}
)
set_target_properties(libA PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
)
# Include paths
target_include_directories(libA
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes>
)
# Link
target_link_libraries(libA)
# Packaging
# Install target to export
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "$ENV{CMAKE_REPO}/libA")
install(TARGETS libA
    EXPORT libA-export
    LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin"
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin"
    RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin"
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include"
)
# Install export
install(EXPORT libA-export
    FILE libATargets.cmake
    CONFIGURATIONS Debug|Release
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/cmake
)
# Install config file
install(FILES libAConfig.cmake
    CONFIGURATIONS Debug|Release
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/cmake
)
```

Content of config file is :

```
get_filename_component(libA_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

if(NOT TARGET libA)
    include("${libA_CMAKE_DIR}/libATargets.cmake")
endif()
```

To be honest, these are collations from various sources I've googled, I understand the generic ideas but not the details and some things might be wrong.

In my second lib (libB), I want to import libA :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(libB VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)
# Required packages
find_package(libA)
# Files
set(PUBLIC_HEADERS
    includes/libB.h
)
set(SOURCE_FILES
    sources/libB.c
)
# Shared library
add_library(libB SHARED
    ${SOURCE_FILES}
)
set_target_properties(libB PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "libA"
)
# Include paths
target_include_directories(libB
    PUBLIC
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes>
)
# Link
target_link_libraries(libB
    PUBLIC libA
)
```

Currently, this gives an error at libB's link :
LNK1181 cannot open input file 'libA-NOTFOUND.obj'

Ho to make this link ? (and look for the proper lib/so file) ?

Am I on the right path for exporting / importing ?

What am I missing ?

Please give a little context and/or some explanations so I can understand what I'm doing ;-)

Comment: You set configurations - `CONFIGURATIONS Debug|Release` - in a wrong way. The symbol `|` is not a part of CMake language, it is a way how documentation describes a **choice**. Proper usage is `CONFIGURATIONS Debug Release`. (A space separates different elements in the list).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that! However, the linking problem persists.

Comment: Hm, it looks like `find_package` doesn't set `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property for `libA` target. Try to use `find_package` with *REQUIRED* option? Also, there are some hints about the code improvement: 1. The command `target_link_libraries(libB PUBLIC libA)` automatically sets `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property. No need to set this property explicitely. 2. Direct using of environment variables, containing the path, may lead to subtle errors. If your `CMAKE_REPO` contains Windows separators ('\'), with `$ENV{CMAKE_REPO}` they are passed to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, which expects `/` separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Tsyvarev 's comments, I fixed the following:

```
CONFIGURATIONS Debug|Release
-->
CONFIGURATIONS Debug Release

set_target_properties(libB PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "libA"
)
-->
set_target_properties(libB PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
)

find_package(libA)
-->
find_package(libA REQUIRED)
```

I cleaned everything, cleared the cache and then it worked! No more linking issue in libB. Thanks a lot Tsyvarev!